# Probability calculation in a gambling game

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, gambling

The problem I am trying to solve is the following:

We are playing a game every day for 100 days. Assuming the winrate is always 75%.

Every day you have the option to either:

1. Play once with the possibility to get 150 dollars if you win
2. Play three times with the possibility to get 50 dollars each time

Which option is better? Does it even make a difference? If yes, how can this be calculated?

Comment: How do you define "better"?  "We are playing a game every day for 100 days"..."play once"..."play three times"...  So, which is it, playing 100 times? playing once? playing three times?  It can't be all of these at once.  Why mention the 100 times in the first place?

Comment: From a game theory standpoint there are some scenarios where you want less variance.  There are other scenarios where you want more variance.  In both scenarios the expected value is the same.  How to calculate this?  This follows easily and directly from the definitions of [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) and [binomial distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) ($150\cdot 0.75$ vs $50\cdot 0.75+50\cdot 0.75+50\cdot 0.75$)

Comment: As previous comments indicate, the expected value of the two options are identical.  Further, while the variance between the two options is signficant over a short period (i.e. a few days), over a $100$ day period, the variance of either option will be neglible.

Comment: @user2661923 ... for certain meanings of "negligible".  I suspect the variance with (1) might be $421875$ while for (2) is a third of that at $140625$

Comment: @Henry In my ignorance of formal Probability Theory, I am not qualified to have an opinion on your comment.  You raise a good point.  My previous comment was intended (*informally*) to indicate that after $100$ days, the chances are overwhelmingly that the actual return will be within $\pm 10\%$ of the expected return.  I know this only from personal (i.e. *anecdotal*) experience with Poker and by observation of gambling casinos.